# Inherit from react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

Hello I'm using typescript + react, and I want to have a base class and several components inherit from the base class.

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IBaseProps {
    title: string;
}

class Base<P extends IBaseProps, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public props: IBaseProps;

    public render() {
        return (
            <h1> Generic Class {this.props.title} </h1>
        );
    }
}

interface IChildProps extends IBaseProps {
    message: string;
}

class Child extends React.Component<IChildProps, undefined> {

    public render() {
        return (
            <h1> Child Class {this.props.title} {this.props.message} </h1>
        );
    }
}
```

But when compiling it throws an error:

```
TS2415: Class 'Base<P, S>' incorrectly extends base class 'Component<P, S>'.
  Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'IBaseProps' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<P>'.
      Type 'IBaseProps' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<P>'.
```

The problem is not inheriting, even this got me the error

```
export class Base<P, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public props: IBaseProps;

    public render() {
        return (
            <h1> Generic Component </h1>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using typescript `v2.3.4`, in case it matter

Comment: Not related to answering your question. But generally inheritance is discouraged to do so. Check out Dan's answer [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8774#issuecomment-272435265)

Comment: I did a little research, and what I did should work, any idea why it doesn't ?

Comment: What's the error you get on your last piece of code?

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: You can't get the same error if you're not using `IBaseProps`.

Comment: You are right, but the problem was solved by this answer, I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to define the `props` member twice, it's enough to do so in the base class:

```
class Base<P extends IBaseProps, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public props: IBaseProps;

    ...
}

class Child extends React.Component<IChildProps, undefined> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The type of `Child.props` will be `IChildProps` because that's what you passed as the generic constraint.

But you don't even need to define it in the base class because `React.Component` will already do that for you, so it should just be:

```
class Base<P extends IBaseProps, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component<IChildProps, undefined> {
    public render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And you will still have `this.props` (with the right type) in all components.

---

#### Edit

In your original code you had this:

```
class Base<P extends IBaseProps, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public props: IBaseProps;
    ...
}
```

But the definition for [React.Component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L183) is:

```
class Component<P, S> {
    ...
    props: Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode }> & Readonly<P>;
    ...
}
```

Which means that you have overridden the `props` member with a type that does not match, and that's what the error says.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help me, I had the props duplicated, but after remove it, the error still remains

Comment: My mistake, this fix it, but still I don't know why